# Rails 4 link to search with elasticsearch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch, searchkick

I am using elasticsearch with searchkick on my rails 4 app.

I just implemented a 'did you mean' feature where it will recommend the correct spelling to users when the query is misspelled.

[image: did you mean]

What is the best way to turn the suggested word into a clickable link that will then search for that instead? Having trouble finding any documentation on doing so.

Here is the code in my view which displays 'did you mean' suggestions:

```
Did you mean: <strong><%= @articles.try(:suggestions).join' ' %></strong>
```

and here is my search method in the articles_controller:

```
@articles = Article.search(params[:q], misspellings: {edit_distance: 2}, suggest: true, fields: ["specific^10", "title", "aka", "category", "tags_name", "nutritiontable"], boost_where: {specific: :exact}, page: params[:page], per_page: 12)
```

Here is the form I use to search my app:

```
<div class="searchbar" id="sea">
    <%= form_tag articles_path, method: :get do %>
        <p>
            <%= text_field_tag :q, params[:q], id:"complete", name:"q", style:"width:550px; height:34px;", :autofocus => true, class: "form-control", placeholder:"Search... " %><br>
            <%= submit_tag "Let's Find Out!", :name => nil, class: "btn btn-default btn-lg", style: "margin-right: 10px;" %>
            <%= link_to "Most Popular", articles_path(:most_popular => true), class:"btn btn-default btn-lg" %>
        </p>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: take the clickable link to the same action in which you have searched before with a new parameter as the suggested word, this would be best way.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Are you able to answer this with the correct code? That way I can accept as an answer. @Deep

Comment: To answer it we will be needing your current code. And if you implemented it using the suggestion then no issues don't post the code.

Comment: Still having trouble. I have added my current search form code. Is there any other specific code you would need to see? @Deep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting some code which may help you, you will need to fix any issues in it but you will get an idea what needs to be done:

```
<div class="searchbar" id="sea">
    <%= form_tag articles_path, method: :get, id: 'search_form' do %>
        <p>
            <%= text_field_tag :q, params[:q], id:"complete", name:"q", style:"width:550px; height:34px;", :autofocus => true, class: "form-control", placeholder:"Search... " %><br>
            <%= submit_tag "Let's Find Out!", :name => nil, class: "btn btn-default btn-lg", style: "margin-right: 10px;" %>
            <%= link_to "Most Popular", articles_path(:most_popular => true), class:"btn btn-default btn-lg" %>
        </p>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

I just added a id to the form.

```
Did you mean: <a id='suggested_word'><strong><%= @articles.try(:suggestions).join' ' %></strong></a>
```

Then in jquery:

```
$("#suggested_word").click(function(){
  var word = $(this).text();
  $("input#complete").val(word);
  $("#search_form").submit();
});
```

This is just a rough code would need much refactoring. What I have done is when any one clicks on the suggestion then the suggested word should be entered in the textbox and that form should be submitted using that word. So it would display the new results with that word.

Now suppose `@articles.try(:suggestions)` returns multiple words then you need to loop them and add anchor tag to each of them.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Works beautifully. Thank you very much @Deep